# How can I prompt the user to assign a new name to each value in a list?

Tags: python, python-3.x, input

So I need to name each item in the list being created from the first user input.
my first line of code is as follows:

```
num_assessment = int(input('How many assessments per student?'))
```

Now I need the user to name each item in the list; for example:

```
How many assessments per student?:2
What type of assessment was assessment 1? Essay
How many marks is the Essay worth? 30
What type of assessment was assessment 2 ? Test
How many marks is the Test worth? 70
```

What is the function I can use to perform this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this one :

```
n = int(input("How many assesments per student?  "))
dct_values = {}
for i in range(1,n+1):
   asesmnt = input("What type of assessment was assessment "+str(i)+"?  
                   ")
   marks = int(input("How many marks is the "+asesmnt+" worth?  "))
   dct_values[i] = [{asesmnt:marks}]
print(dct_values)
```

It will store all the values in a dict , O/P willl be like this :

```
{1: [{'Essay': 30}], 2: [{'Test': 70}]}
```

Answer (score 1):

A dictionary with a `for` loop is one way to structure your data. Below is an example.

```
num_assessment = int(input('How many assesments per student?\n'))

data = {}

for i in range(1, num_assessment+1):
    data_type = input('What type of assessment was assessment {0}?\n'.format(i))
    data_marks = int(input('How many marks is the {0} worth?\n'.format(data_type)))
    data[i] = {'type': data_type, 'marks': data_marks}
```

**Example**

```
How many assesments per student?
2
What type of assessment was assessment 1?
essay
How many marks is the essay worth?
30
What type of assessment was assessment 2?
assignment
How many marks is the assignment worth?
50
```

**Result**

```
print(data)
{1: {'marks': 30, 'type': 'essay'}, 2: {'marks': 50, 'type': 'assignment'}}
```